# What is Qemu code flow for CPU operation using KVM mode?

Tags: qemu, instrumentation, trace, kvm

If I want to profile a VM's CPU load when running Qemu with KVM mode
using static probe instrumentation, where (which file/function) should
I put my trace points?

I have tried to use the default trace-points (trace-events file)
without any success.
I have googling the web, but the best information I got is information
on TCG mode code flow.
Can anyone give the same information on KVM mode?

Answer (score -2):

I have been trying to do the same with trace-events but has not helped.

Either add new events to the trace-events file or attach gdb to qemu and step through.